# Google analytics v4 gtag: default snippet + debugger extension causes javascript console warning

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have copied the script tags exactly as given by Google Analytics v4, into the `<head>` section of the site.  No other gtag code added yet.

I am using the chrome extensions 'Google Analytics Debugger' to test it

In the console output, I get this (G-XXXXXXX where the actual GA v4 property appears):

```
Processing GTAG command: ["config", "G-XXXXXXX"]
  GTAG Command: "config", target: "G-XXXXXXX", configuration: {}
     Invalid event parameter "_ipe" on event "gtag.config", parameter will not be logged
```

and further down:

```
  Sending event "page_view" to undefined
```

Here is the snippet:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXX');
</script>
```

Is it possible something is not set up correctly in Analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't trust an outdated extension for debugging.

[image]

Either use the network tab to debug your calls, or if you want some convenience - use [Adswerve's datalayer inspector extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom?hl=en) instead of what google made.

If the issue persists, try downloading your GTM container and look for "_ipe". Make sure it's not your code in GTM. That is, of course, if you have any logic deployed in GTM.

Comment: The analytics v4 setup guide specifically instructs to use this extension.  But the page views are coming through in analytics, so I guess it's just Google sucking at documentation.  Thanks for the Adswerve tip

Comment: Came here searching for the same thing. All alternate methods for debugging validate what's being recorded: viewing the Network request parameters, exporting reports from GA4, etc. confirm the data was received and processed.